# Anti-flag transitive projective planes

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups, projective-geometry, incidence-geometry

Let $\Gamma$ be an axiomatic projective plane, and suppose its automorphism group acts transitively on the *anti-flags* (the point-line pairs $(u,V)$ such that $u$ is not incident with $V$).

In the infinite case, this property is not strong enough to conclude that the planes are Moufang (there are counter examples), but I'm pretty sure that in the finite case, it is well known that such planes are Desarguesian (that is, isomorphic to a plane $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for some finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$).

Can anyone give me a good reference for the last "result" ? (As I had no success finding one.)

Thanks !

Comment: Cameron and Kantor credit this result to Ostrom and Wagner. Theorem 2.1 in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869379900905